# I keep getting the same error message: Segment Fault (core dumped)

Tags: c++, vector, coredump

I am very new to C++ and all things computer-related, so go easy. I am trying to use a vector for the first time in an assignment for my class. I managed to get my code to compile, but halfway through running, the code reads `segment fault (core dumped)`. I don't know how to use gdb to pinpoint the exact line but I know it occurs in the names function during the loop to organize the names in alphabetical order. I understand there is something wrong with the sizing of my vector, but I don't know how to fix it. I also need a simple solution, as I am not in an advanced class, and can only use what I have learned thus far in class.

I also am aware of how silly my names for things are, and the fact that I have crammed so much into my names function...

Please help me, despite the confusing nature of my code!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int choice(int);
void sortAndSend(vector<string> &names);

int main()
{
    ofstream outputFile;
    int numOfNames;
    int count = 0;
    numOfNames = choice(numOfNames);

    vector<string> names(numOfNames);
    sortAndSend(names);

    outputFile.close();
    return 0;
}

int choice(int a)
{
    cout << "Select a number 1-5 that reflects how many names" << endl
         << "you would like to enter." << endl;
    cin >> a;
    cout << "You have selected " << a << " names." << endl << endl;
    return a;
}

void sortAndSend(vector<string> &names)
{
    ofstream outputFile;
    string name;
    string a;

    cout << "You will be asked to enter " << names.size() << " names." << endl
         << "You may enter each individual's "
         << "last name first, followed by the individual's first name, "
         << "then middle name (if applicable)." << endl
         << "Do NOT include any commas." << endl << endl;
    cin.ignore();
    for (int count = 0; count < names.size(); count++)                           //Allows user to enter specified # of names
    {
        cout << "Enter a name now: ";
        getline(cin, name);
        names[count] = name;
        cout << endl << "You have entered " << names[count] << endl << endl;
    }

    for (int count = 0; count < names.size(); count++)
    {
        cout << names[count] << endl;
    }
    for (int count = 0; count < names.size(); count++)
                                      //Arranges names in alphabetical order
                                      //Error occurs here
    {
        while (names[count] > names[count + 1])
        {
            a = names[count + 1];
            names[count + 1] = names[count];
            names[count] = a;
        }
    }
    cout << "Your names are now alphebetized" << endl << endl;
    cout << "This is what is being copied to the file named"
         << " 'AlphabeticalOrderEC.txt': " << endl;

    for (int count = 0; count < names.size(); count++)         //Prints     names in alphabetical order
    {
        cout << names[count] << endl;
    }

    outputFile.open("AlphabeticalOrderEC");                    //Prints names into file
    for (int count = 0; count < names.size(); count++)
    {
        outputFile << names[count] << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've edited to change the typo 'gbd' to 'gdb', but wanted to make sure you were actually using the right command!  `gdb <executable>` and then type 'run' after you're in gdb.  When it segfaults, type `bt` to get a backtrace.

Comment: If `count` == `names.size() - 1` then `count + 1` == `names.size()` and `names[count + 1]` is outside the bounds of the array.

Comment: Thank you for the help, and the typo fix! That was an easy fix! I feel silly for having missed that.

Comment: A debugger is a necessity for any serious programming - learn how to use one! You could also use an easier gui debugger to develop your code, but remember to test it on your target compiler as they can handle certain things differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to access adress that doesn't blongs to the vector. See at this part of your code :

```
for (int count = 0; count < names.size(); count++)
{
    while (names[count] > names[count + 1])
    {
        a = names[count + 1];
        names[count + 1] = names[count];
        names[count] = a;
    }
}
```

you should'n use `count + 1`, you must do it only when count is less than `names.size()-1`. You should find another logic that can replace this part of your code. It's like trying to access the 11th element of an array that has only 10.